# OOP in python programming

Tags: python

Hello guys am kind of new to programming in python language and was hoping if I get assistance from you. The question is this:

1. Create a class called ShoppingCart.
2. Create a constructor that takes no arguments and sets the total
   attribute to zero, and initializes an empty dict attribute named
   items.
3. Create a method add_item that requires item_name, quantity and price
   arguments. This method should add the cost of the added items to the
   current value of total. It should also add an entry to the items
   dict such that the key is the item_name and the value is the
   quantity of the item.
4. Create a method remove_item that requires similar arguments as
   add_item. It should remove items that have been added to the
   shopping cart and are not required. This method should deduct the
   cost of the removed items from the current total and also update the
   items dict accordingly.
5. If the quantity of an item to be removed exceeds the current
   quantity of that item in the cart, assume that all entries of that
   item are to be removed.
6. Create a method checkout that takes in cash_paid and returns the
   value of balance from the payment. If cash_paid is not enough to
   cover the total, return "Cash paid not enough".
7. Create a class called Shop that has a constructor which takes no
   arguments and initializes an attribute called quantity at 100. Make
   sure Shop inherits from ShoppingCart.
8. In the Shop class, override the remove_item method, such that
   calling Shop's remove_item with no arguments decrements quantity by
   one

And here is my code

```
class ShoppingCart(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.items = dict()

    def add_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
        if item_name != None and quantity >= 1:
            self.items.update({item_name: quantity})
        if quantity and price >= 1:
            self.total += (quantity * price)

    def remove_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
        self.total -= (quantity * price)
        try:
            if quantity >= self.items[item_name]:
                self.items.pop(item_name, None)
            self.items[item_name] -= quantity
        except(KeyError, RuntimeError):
            pass

    def checkout(self, cash_paid):
        balance = 0
        if cash_paid < self.total:
            return "Cash paid not enough"
        balance = cash_paid - self.total
        return balance


class Shop(ShoppingCart):

    def __init__(self):
        self.quantity = 100

    def remove_item(self):
        self.quantity -= 1
```

And the unittest

```
import unittest;

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.cart = ShoppingCart()
        self.shop = Shop()

    def test_cart_property_initialization(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 0, msg='Initial value of total not correct')
        self.assertIsInstance(self.cart.items, dict, msg='Items is not a dictionary')

    def test_add_item(self):
        self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 30, msg='Cart total not correct after adding items')
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Mango'], 3, msg='Quantity of items not correct after adding item')

    def test_add_item_hidden(self):
        self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
        self.cart.add_item('Orange', 16, 10)
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 190, msg='Cart total not correct after adding items')
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Orange'], 16, msg='Quantity of items not correct after adding item')

    def test_remove_item(self):
        self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
        self.cart.remove_item('Mango', 2, 10)
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 10, msg='Cart total not correct after removing item')
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Mango'], 1, msg='Quantity of items not correct after removing item')

    def test_remove_item_hidden(self):
        self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
        self.cart.add_item('Orange', 16, 10)
        self.cart.remove_item('Mango', 2, 10)
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 170, msg='Cart total not correct after removing item')
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Mango'], 1, msg='Quantity of items not correct after removing item')
        self.cart.remove_item('Mango', 2, 10)
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 160, msg='Cart total not correct after removing item')
        with self.assertRaises(KeyError):
            self.cart.items['Mango']

    def test_checkout_returns_correct_value(self):
        self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
        self.cart.add_item('Orange', 16, 10)
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.checkout(265), 75, msg='Balance of checkout not correct')
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.checkout(25), 'Cash paid not enough', msg='Balance of checkout not correct')


    def test_shop_is_instance_of_shopping_cart(self):
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(self.shop, ShoppingCart), msg='Shop is not a subclass of ShoppingCart')

    def test_shop_initializaton(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.shop.quantity, 100, msg='Shop quantity not initialized correctly')

    def test_shop_remove_item_method(self):
        for i in range(15):
            self.shop.remove_item()

        self.assertEqual(self.shop.quantity, 85)
```

Now after running the unitest am getting this error message:

> "150 != 160 : Cart total not correct after removing item"

Anyone willing to help please will appreciate any guidelines.

Comment: which unit test? please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: in `test_remove_item_hidden` you assert that the cart total should be 170, then remove two Mangos of value 10, and then assert that the total should be 160.

Comment: This seems like homework....

Comment: Whoever wrote this "exercise" should stop pretending teaching OOP - they clearly don't grasp the whole concept... "Shop" inheriting from "Cart" and overriding `remove_item` with an incompatible sig and a totaly unrelated behaviour #facepalm

Comment: Why would you want to catch the `RuntimeError`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like in the `remove_item` class attribute, you update the total value of the cart prior to determining if you are removing more items then you have.

If you modify it so you check the item quantity first and then subtract the total number available if less than the total number wanted to be removed... it should fix the problem

```
def remove_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
    try:
        if quantity >= self.items[item_name]:

            self.total -= (self.items[item_name] * price)
            self.items.pop(item_name, None)
        else:
            self.items[item_name] -= quantity
            self.total -= (quantity * price)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the edit... we still want to de-increment the quantity if when removing the item in question, it leaves some in the cart still.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is wrong. Here your code checks that the cart total is 170 cash:

```
self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 170, msg='Cart total not correct after removing item')
```

Then it removes 2 items at 10 cash each:

```
self.cart.remove_item('Mango', 2, 10)
```

Then it checks to see if there is 160 cash remaining:

```
self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 160, msg='Cart total not correct after removing item')
```

but it hasn't, it has 150 cash, which is what anyone would expect (`170 - 20 = 150`).

Comment: he had 3 mangoes, removed 2 and removed 2 more, so the 160 is correct

Comment: @MaartenFabré, the total was 170 *after* he removed the first 2 mangoes.

Comment: Yes, but then there is only 1 mango left, so even when asked to remove 2 mangoes, it should only substract that 1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `add_item` method you are not updating the item so each time you add the same item it doesn't update it just resigns the `item_name` and `quantity` again and forgets about the previous values so this is what your `add_item` method should look like:

```
def add_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
    self.total += price*quantity
    self.items.update({item_name: quantity})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
class ShoppingCart(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.items = dict()

    def add_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
        if item_name != None and quantity >= 1:
            self.items.update({item_name: quantity})
        if quantity and price >= 1:
            self.total += (quantity * price)

    def remove_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
        try:
            if quantity >= self.items[item_name]:

                self.total -= (self.items[item_name] * price)
                self.items.pop(item_name, None)

            else:
              self.items[item_name] -= quantity
              self.total -= (quantity * price)
        except IOError:
            print
            "Error: can\'t find file or read data"

    def checkout(self, cash_paid):
        balance = 0
        if cash_paid < self.total:
            return "Cash paid not enough"
        balance = cash_paid - self.total
        return balance


class Shop(ShoppingCart):   
    def __init__(self):
        self.quantity = 100

    def remove_item(self):
        self.quantity -= 1
```